# Basic question about minus sign for negative operator

Tags: r, operators

I am not sure I understand the behaviour of the minus sign.

```
x <- 10:1
y <- c(4, 7)
x[y]
# [1] 7 4
x[-y]
# [1] 10  9  8  6  5  3  2  1
```

So the `-` sign in `x[-y]` is understood as items of `x` that are not `y`.

```
x <- 10:1
y <- 1:10
x[-y]
# integer(0)
```

Again logical, if `y` has all the element of `x`, `x[-y]` should be empty.

Now if `y` is itself empty, you'd expect that `x[-y]` should list all the elements of `x`.
However:

```
x <- 10:1
y <- integer()
x[-y]
# integer(0)
```

What is it that I am not understanding?
Is there any other operator to do what I want (i.e. list the elements of `x` that are not in `y`, and thus list all elements of `x` is `y` is empty)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jay.sf's answer explains how to get what you want.  I just wanted to add a bit more explanation, and give a suggestion for a different approach.

When you say `x[-y]`, the minus sign doesn't have any special meaning:  it just changes the sign of the elements of `y`.  It will give the same result as

```
z <- -y
x[z]
```

When `y` is empty, `z` will be empty as well, so `x[y]` is the same as `x[-y]`.

My recommendation is to use logical indices when you want to do logical operations on them.  So you might have been doing this:

```
y <- which(x %% 50 == 11)
```

to choose the entries which meet the condition `x %% 50 == 11`.  Then if you
happen to have a vector where nothing meets the condition, you get an empty `y`.  A better approach is

```
y <- x %% 50 == 11
```

so that `y` is a vector of all `FALSE` values.  If you want the complement, use

```
x[!y]
```

and you'll get all of `x`.

Comment: Got it! Indeed I used the `which` command to get my list of index. I understand how your approach is superior. I'll try to implement it (though it will be difficult because I generate my list of index using a loop to nest several conditions that need to be matched).

Comment: In that sort of situation, you can use "or", e.g. `y <- y | new_condition` to "increment" `y` to hold the cases meeting the new condition.  Don't use the double bar `||` which is for scalar tests, use the vectorized single one `|`.

Answer (score 2):

> So the - sign in x[-y] is understood as items of x that are not y.

No, `y` is used as indices of `x` here. You can think of it like this:

```
setNames(x, paste0('x', seq_along(x)))
#  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10 
# 10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1 

x[-c(4, 7)]  ## delete x4 and x7
# [1] 10  9  8  6  5  3  2  1
```

If you want elements in `x` that are not in `y` you need to say:

```
x[!x %in% y]
# [1] 10  9  8  6  5  3  2  1

y1 <- NULL
x[!x %in% y1]
# [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Or:

```
setdiff(x, y)
# [1] 10  9  8  6  5  3  2  1

setdiff(x, y1)
# [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Accordingly, in this one we delete all element indices from `1:10`, and since we have only 10 elements in `x` we get the empty vector:

```
x[-(1:10)]
# numeric(0)
```

For the last one, we may read in documetation `help("Extract")`, that *"an empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace all the entries but keep the attributes."*

```
x[-integer()]
# integer(0)
```

### How to delete nothing

If we want to delete nothing, we need an index that is higher than the number of elements in `x`,

```
x[-11]
# [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

where we could do dynamically:

```
x[-.Machine$integer.max]
# [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Comment: But does that answer TO‘s question? So if y is an empty integer, and they do `x[-y]`, intuitively this means „delete nothing from x“, but that‘s not the case.

Comment: @deschen Added that one to my answer, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I wasn't quite clear. I understand that `y` contains indexes. But that's what I am trying to do. I have a list `y` of indexes and I want to keep the elements of `x` that are not in that list of indexes, and thus keep all of `x` if `y` is empty. I imagine I could use `x[!(x %in% x[y])]` . Would it be the best solution? thanks!

Comment: @benjou Sure (actually the parentheses are superfluous), I added that to my answer.

Comment: @jay.sf SUperb, thanks!